# Hibernate unknown entity (not missing @Entity or import javax.persistence.Entity )

Tags: java, hibernate

I've got a really simple class:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Column(name = "firstName")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "lastName")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;


    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

I call it using this main:

```
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        User u = new User();
        u.setEmail("david@hello.co.uk");
        u.setFirstName("David");
        u.setLastName("Gray");

        session.save(u);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        System.out.println("Record committed");
        session.close();


    }

}
```

I keep getting this MappingException:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: org.assessme.com.entity.User
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1172)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1316)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:670)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:662)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:658)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:352)
    at $Proxy4.save(Unknown Source)
    at Main.main(Main.java:20)
```

My HibernateUtil is:

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

    public static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure();
            serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();     
            return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        return sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

Does anyone have any ideas as I've looked at so many duplicates but the resolutions don't appear to work for me.  This is my hibernate.cfg.xml:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/ssme</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">mypassword</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should use `AnnotationConfiguration` instead of `Configuration` and then call

```
configuration.addAnnotatedClass(User.class);
```

to add your class to the list of mapped classes.

Comment: Ah, should I do this in my hibernateutil, is it best practice to do that all in one class would you say?

Comment: Depends on the size of your project. If you have only a couple of mapped classes you can do this in your `HibernateUtil`. For bigger projects you can e.g. use reflection to add all classes of a specific package to hibernate, or you can use a mapping config file.

Answer (score 14):

Add to `hibernate.cfg.xml` before `</session-factory>` this:

```
<mapping class="org.assessme.com.entity.User" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Consider using `AnnotationConfiguration` described [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/cfg/AnnotationConfiguration.html).

You could either use its `addClass(User.class)` method, or if you're persisting multiple entities use the `addPackage("org.assessme.com.entity")` method.

You're kind of reinventing the wheel with this `HibernateUtil` class. Consider using Spring so you can leverage something like its `AnnotationSessionFactoryBean`.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any `persistence.xml` or `hibernate.cfg.xml`? If you have to add your mapping class in it so hibernate get understand your class is mapping to the database. If you have `hibernate.cfg.xml` you can add like this

```
<mapping class="com.entity.Users"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I forgot to add the hbm.xml mapping into my cfg.xml file. As soon as I added it, this exception disappeared.

```
<mapping resource="com/mycompany/backend/hibernate/CServiceCenters.hbm.xml" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Add below line to your hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<mapping class="fully qualified Entity class name"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced a similar issue but it got resolved when I appended the MySQL version in the dialect.
org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect

Compatibility issue it seems.