# What does 'Unknown entity' mean in a Hibernate related exception?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm a *Hibernate* newbie, separating a module out of a legacy Java-Hibernate project. When exceptions are thrown, some `Unknown entity:` messages are also printed to the error log. From other related [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9980795/640378), I see that it can be fixed. However, I'm curious what the meaning of `Unknown entity` actually is.

What is the error log trying to say?
Is it just telling me what the entity classes involved are?
How would my error log change if I fix the config to include entity classes?

I can't try to reproduce the error, so there's no way I can see how the config change will impact the error log when the same exception happens again.

See a sample exception here:

```
[2015 Feb 02 00:15:19.836] [Camel (camel) thread #0 - seda://exceptions] ERROR (TradeDAO.java:75) - Unknown entity: myProject.data.util.TradeExceptionObject
[2015 Feb 02 00:15:19.857] [Camel (camel) thread #0 - seda://exceptions] ERROR (TradeExceptionHandler.java:83) - Unknown entity: myProject.data.util.TradeExceptionObject
```

#### Edit 2

hib.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="myProject.data.Trade" table="TRADE" optimistic-lock="version">
</hibernate-mapping>
```

#### Edit 1

```
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;

public class TradeExceptionHandler implements Processor {

    private TradeDAO tradeDao;

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        // ... code here

        try {
            tradeDao.saveOrUpdate(excptObj);
/* LINE 83 */   } catch(Exception ignore) {LOG.error(ignore.getMessage());}
        // ... code here    
    }

    public void setTradeDao(TradeDAO tradeDao) {
    }

    public TradeDAO getTradeDao() {
    }

}
```

TradeDAO.java

```
package myProject.persistence;

import org.hibernate.*;

public class TradeDAO implements DisposableBean {

    public TradeDAO() {
    }

    public <E> void saveOrUpdate(E obj) throws Exception {
        saveOrUpdate(obj,0);
    }

    private <E> void saveOrUpdate(E obj,int attempt) throws Exception {
        Transaction tx = null;
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        try {
            if(obj != null) {
                tx = session.beginTransaction();
                add(obj, session);
                session.getTransaction().commit();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            LOG.error(ex.getMessage());
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    /* Make a query to database using hibernate */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <E> List<E> get(final  Class<E> clz, 
            Map<? extends String, Object> eqCond){
    }

    private <E> void add(E obj, Session session) {
        session.saveOrUpdate(obj);
        session.flush();
    }   
}
```

Comment: You should provide the stack trace of the exception you're asking about. Not the stack trace of an https communication failure.

Comment: @JBNizet The https communication failure exception resulted in this hibernate entity error. Sure, it might not have anything to do with hibernate. But, what I meant was that I'm unable to reproduce the http error and hence can't reproduce the hibernate entity error. The exception handling code for the https error results in the hibernate error. **The last 2 lines you see in the error message are all that I see related to hibernate on the error log.**

Comment: Without code and without the stack trace of the actual exception, it's quite hard to answer. My guess is that TradeExceptionObject is not an entity at all, or is an entity but not declared in hibernate's configuration file and thus not considered as an entity by Hibernate.

Comment: @JBNizet I'm [not clear](https://premaseem.wordpress.com/2011/01/28/hibernate-what-is-entity/) on what an entity is. If an entity is just a pojo by definition, then you might be right. See updated code above.

Comment: An entity is annotated as `@Entity`.

Comment: If you don't know what an entity is, then you should read a JPA/Hibernate tutorial. That's quite essential to understand.

Comment: @JBNizet I see that an entity is a POJO. Here, `TradeExceptionObject` is not a POJO, neither is `TradeDAO` (a data access object). There is a `Trade` class which is the class of interest, but is declared in hbm.xml. See edit 2 above. So, I'm wondering what hibernate is trying to tell me when it prints 'Unknown entity' in the error log.

Comment: How could an object not be a POJO? What do you think a POJO is? The Trade class is not the class of interest: the exception message complains about `TradeExceptionObject`not being a known entity. Not `Trade`.

Comment: @JBNizet Well, I meant as in: it is not a class that models a database table. But, you are right, I need to read up on the material.

Comment: An entity is that: a class that you can persist in a database table.